# Error: Cannot find module 'd3'

Tags: node.js, d3.js, vega, vincent

I'm trying to run a node script ([vg2svg](https://github.com/trifacta/vega/wiki/Headless-Mode)), but get this error:

```js
Error: Cannot find module 'd3'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/my_user/repos/vega/index.js:10:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

I've installed nodejs and npm with macports, and d3 with `npm install d3`, but d3 doesn't seem to be recognized.

When I run node from the macports dir (`/opt/local/bin/`) and do `require("d3")`  there's some sensible output, but when I `cd` to a different dir I get that `Cannot find module` error again.

I've also tried a few variations on `export NODE_PATH=.:/opt/local/bin/:/Users/my_user/repos/vega/` but that didn't seem to help either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to require a module you must do `npm install` you should do `npm init` first and both should be run from the root directory of where your project resides directory.